# Take element from one javascript object and save into another

Tags: javascript

I want to take an element from one javascript object and save into another.

My object looks like this:

```
let obj = {
  countries: [{
    'Country name': "Russia",
    Flag: "RU",
    Population: 146774178
  }, {
    'Country name': "Turkey",
    Flag: "TR",
    Population: 83154997
  }]
};
```

My function can only alert specific items:

```
function custom() {
  for (var key in obj.countries) {
    var countryn = obj.countries[key]['Country name'];
    if(countryn = "Turkey") {
      alert(countryn);
    }
}}
```

In this function, if I find a country in the object, I would like to take the whole element and save it in a new object like this:

```
{
  "countries": [
    {
      "Country name": "Turkey",
      "Flag": "TR",
      "Population": 83154997
    }
  ]
}
```

How could I achieve that?

Comment: just to clarify, you want to move the matching country to another countries array contained in another object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you are comparing with incorrect condition in `if`. There should be `==` instead of `=` like `if(countryn == "Turkey")`.

To get your desired result declare array at top of function. inside `if(countryn == "Turkey")` add matching object to array. Object can be get through `obj.countries[key]`.

Or you can simple use `filter` like shown in `custom2` as `return obj.countries.filter(x => x['Country name'] == "Turkey");`

```js
let obj = {
  countries: [{
    'Country name': "Russia",
    Flag: "RU",
    Population: 146774178
  }, {
    'Country name': "Turkey",
    Flag: "TR",
    Population: 83154997
  }]
};

function custom() {
  let customCountry = [];
  for (var key in obj.countries) {
    var countryn = obj.countries[key]['Country name'];
    if (countryn == "Turkey") {
      customCountry.push(obj.countries[key]);
    }
  }
  return { countries: customCountry };
}

function custom2() {
  let countries = obj.countries.filter(x => x['Country name'] == "Turkey");
  return { countries: countries }; 
}

console.log(custom(obj));
console.log(custom2(obj));
```

Comment: With custom2 I get: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded or that filter is not defined. First option worked well.

Comment: It shouldn't return such error. Must be some specific scenario I guess. You can check it with `Run code snippet` and confirm that it is working. Still if you could show me `object` for which you are getting such error then I may be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare an empty array with name `filteredCountries`, and push the required `country` object in the `filteredCountries` array.

```
const filteredCountries = [];

function custom() {
  for (var key in obj.countries) {
    var countryn = obj.countries[key]['Country name'];
    if(countryn == "Turkey") {
       filteredCountries.push(obj.countries[key]);
    }
}}
```

Alternatively, you can also use the `array.filter` ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)) method to simplify your code:

```
const filteredCountries = obj.countries.filter(country => country['Country Name'] === 'Turkey'));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can achieve this. One way is to filter the existing array.

```js
const countryData = [{
  name: "Russia",
  flag: "RU"
}, {
  name: "Turkey",
  flag: "TR"
}];

function custom(countryData) {
  return countryData.filter(country => country.name === "Turkey");
}

const result = custom(countryData);
console.log(result);
```